# How to pass custom headers in grafana data source?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I tried to find how to pass custom header in grafana data source.
There is no option to set custom header in grafana data source.
I wanted to set grafana data source as prometheus and set some custom header.
Is there any way to do that other than editing grafana.ini file?

Comment: There is a [ticket on grafana github](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/12779) for this feature.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Thanks for pointing out. It is indeed a very useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

On the new versions of Grafana, you are able to pass custom headers to the data source.

On this site https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning

lookup for Custom HTTP headers for data sources